# How to use htaccess Rewrite rule for just part of a url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to create a rewrite rule in my httacess file for part of the url. I want to rewrite the url if the request contains a specific string. For example change the url only if contains `/members/`

So

```
mydomain.com/members/  
mydomain.com/members/activity/ros1...  
mydomain.com/members/ay/bd...
```

ALL above should change to another url because matches /members/ string in the url

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET /members/(.*)  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

---

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/members(.*)   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

I have tried various combinations but does not seem to work. I'm sure I'm doing something really wrong as not on expert on this. Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/members
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/$1 [R, 301]
```

Would be something i would try to redirect a request for /members and send them to another domain. (with the same request uri).  Further info on mod_rewrite can be found https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `F` flag in your rewrites. The flag is to send the **`Forbidden`** status back to client. If you want to redirect the user to another URL, you'll need to pass that URL as the second parameter to `RewriteRule` directive with the `R` flag:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^members\b http://some-other-website.com [R]
```